# How to print cities correctly using recursive?

Tags: c, recursive-datastructures

Hmm.. I've an hard time to do this print recursively.. can someone fix my code?
its very hard to understand how to print all direction of the city where the next city also have an all direction in it.

cityHead will be the center of all city(can be at middle or other) and pointer of array i use it for store the city after the citynode created. So the thing i want right now is the print recursively. First is the maincenter city print, and the it will check the other 4 direction. and if the first direction city->west got city on it it will print it first. until all city got print it will change into city->west and print city-west all 4 direction if there is any city at the city->west direction..

```
struct cities{
    char name[100];
    cities *e,*w,*s,*n;

}*cityHead,*city[100];

    void printcity(cities *cityHead,int e,int w,int s,int n){
     if(cityHead){

        if(cityHead->w != NULL && w != 1){
            printf("--");
            printf("West: %s\n",cityHead->w->name);
            printcity(cityHead->w,1,0,0,0);
        }else{
            printf("--");
            printf("West: None\n");
        }

        if(cityHead->e != NULL && e != 1){
            printf("--");
            printf("East: %s\n",cityHead->e->name);
            printcity(cityHead->e,0,1,0,0);

        }else{
            printf("--");
            printf("East: None\n");
        }

        if(cityHead->s != NULL && s != 1){
            printf("--");
            printf("South: %s\n",cityHead->s->name);
            printcity(cityHead->s,0,0,0,1);

        }else{
            printf("--");
            printf("South: None\n");
        }

        if(cityHead->n != NULL && n != 1){
            printf("--");
            printf("North: %s\n",cityHead->n->name);
            printcity(cityHead->s,0,0,1,0);

        }else{
            printf("--");
            printf("North: None\n");
        }
    }
    }

    cities * newcity(char name[])
    {
       cities *temp = (cities)malloc(sizeof(cities));

       strcpy(temp->name,name);
       temp->e = temp->n = temp->s = temp->w = NULL;
       return temp;
     }
```

Comment: Can you show the definition of `cities`?

Comment: And also tell us more about what you want to do with the printing. As is, the question is not clear.

Comment: Looks to be more of a graph than a linked list.

Comment: cities *newcity(char name[]){
 cities *temp = (cities*)malloc(sizeof(cities));
 strcpy(temp->name,name);
 temp->e = temp->n = temp->s = temp->w = NULL;
 return temp;
}

Comment: the thing i want to print is the city where we start from the center of the city, first it will print the center, and check 4 direction which is east,west,south,north, then it will print east: none if the direction got no city there, and print east: cityX if there is city, it will be done recursively

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what you want (it is still not clear) and show the definition of `cities`, not how you allocate it. Also, show your first call of the function (e.g. in `main`).

Comment: Also please provide an example for output how you want it and the corespoding input

Comment: @Reve I edited your question to give the defintion of *newcity* you put in a remark, next time edit yourself your question rather than to use a remark. Out of that since the beginning it is requested to have the definition of *cities* (a *struct* very probably) and more material. Without we cannot help you

Comment: @Jabberwocky may be the OP just does not understand what we ask for, few days ago I was going to be crazy (supposing I am not already) because I asked several times the definition of a function but for the OP 'definition' was not about the code but about a textual description of the goal :-)

Comment: @Reve please [edit] your question and add all relevant information including code _there_ and not in comments.Especially show us the definition of the type `cities`.

Comment: The malloc looks bad anyway - seems to try to cast a pointer to a struct:(

Comment: @MartinJames yes OP missed the "_*_", it was already the case in the remark giving definition of *newcity* . We are in C, the cast is useless on _malloc_ result

Comment: Finally I think understood the problem, the OP can thank the confinement at least in France because of the covid19 :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

very probably a reasonable definition of *cities* (which was much better named *City*, no reason so have it plural) is

```
typedef struct cities {
  char name[64];
  struct cities * e;
  struct cities * n;
  struct cities * s;
  struct cities * w;
} cities;
```

and your problem is to write all the links without entering in an infinite loop

A first thing to do is to immediately modify your program because you indicate the west etc of a city but you do not indicate for which city, so for instance :

```
  if(cityHead->w != NULL && w != 1){
      printf("--");
      printf("%s West: %s\n", cityHead->name, cityHead->w->name);
      printcity(cityHead->w,1,0,0,0);
  }else{
      printf("--");
      printf("%s West: None\n", cityHead->name);
  }
```

and so on for the other cases

Let see with 2 cities with the change :

```
int main()
{
  cities * c1 = newcity("c1");
  cities * c2 = newcity("c2");

  c1->e = c2;
  c2->w = c1;

  printcity(c1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
--c1 West: None
--c1 East: c2
--c2 West: None
--c2 East: None
--c2 South: None
--c2 North: None
--c1 South: None
--c1 North: None
```

and we see the program does not indicate the east of *c2* is *c1*

The reason is simple, for instance in

> ```
>  if(cityHead->w != NULL && w != 1){
>      printf("--");
>      printf("%s West: %s\n", cityHead->name, cityHead->w->name);
>      printcity(cityHead->w,1,0,0,0);
>  }else{
>      printf("--");
>      printf("%s West: None\n", cityHead->name);
>  }
> ```

*w* is clearly used to not enter in an infinite, but it also blocks the  *printf*

So let modify it to have :

```
  if(cityHead->w != NULL){
      printf("--");
      printf("%s West: %s\n", cityHead->name, cityHead->w->name);
      if (w != 1)
        printcity(cityHead->w,1,0,0,0);
  }else{
      printf("--");
      printf("%s West: None\n", cityHead->name);
  }
```

There is also an error when you want to manage the north, the recursive call is :

> ```
> printcity(cityHead->s,0,0,1,0);
> ```

but it must be

```
printcity(cityHead->n,0,0,1,0);
```

So finaly :

```
void printcity(cities *cityHead,int e,int w,int s,int n){
 if(cityHead){

    if(cityHead->w != NULL){
        printf("--");
        printf("%s West: %s\n", cityHead->name, cityHead->w->name);
        if (w != 1)
          printcity(cityHead->w,1,0,0,0);
    }else{
        printf("--");
        printf("%s West: None\n", cityHead->name);
    }

    if(cityHead->e != NULL){
        printf("--");
        printf("%s East: %s\n", cityHead->name,cityHead->e->name);
        if (e != 1)
          printcity(cityHead->e,0,1,0,0);

    }else{
        printf("--");
        printf("%s East: None\n", cityHead->name);
    }

    if(cityHead->s != NULL){
        printf("--");
        printf("%s South: %s\n", cityHead->name,cityHead->s->name);
        if (s != 1)
          printcity(cityHead->s,0,0,0,1);

    }else{
        printf("--");
        printf("%s South: None\n", cityHead->name);
    }

    if(cityHead->n != NULL){
        printf("--");
        printf("%s North: %s\n", cityHead->name,cityHead->n->name);
        if (n != 1)
          printcity(cityHead->n,0,0,1,0);

    }else{
        printf("--");
        printf("%s North: None\n", cityHead->name);
    }
 }
}
```

out of that let notice the initial test

> ```
> if(cityHead){
> ```

is only useful if *printcity* is initially called with NULL, the function itself never recur with a NULL

Now the execution is :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
--c1 West: None
--c1 East: c2
--c2 West: c1
--c2 East: None
--c2 South: None
--c2 North: None
--c1 South: None
--c1 North: None
```

If we have 4 cities making a square :

```
int main()
{
  cities * c1 = newcity("c1");
  cities * c2 = newcity("c2");
  cities * c3 = newcity("c3");
  cities * c4 = newcity("c4");

  c1->e = c2;
  c2->w = c1;

  c1->s = c3;
  c3->n = c1;

  c2->s = c4;
  c4->n = c2;

  c4->w = c3;
  c3->e = c4;

  printcity(c1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

the execution write a verrrrrrrry long times before to stop after too many recursions and a too large stack.

The reason is the *int* in parameters do not have enough extend in the graph.

A way to solve is to add a field in the *struct* to mark if the city was already managed. But out of modifying the *struct* that requests at the end to again go through the graph to clear the mark.

An other way is to save the already managed cities in a list, giving that list in parameter :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct cities {
  char name[64];
  struct cities * e;
  struct cities * n;
  struct cities * s;
  struct cities * w;
} cities;

typedef struct CityList {
  cities * city;
  struct CityList * next;
} CityList;

int isPresent(cities * c, CityList * l)
{
  while (l) {
    if (l->city == c)
      return 1;
    l = l->next;
  }
  return 0;
}

void add(cities * city, CityList ** l)
{
  CityList * cell = malloc(sizeof(CityList));

  cell->city = city;
  cell->next = *l;
  *l = cell;
}

void clear(CityList ** l)
{
  while (*l) {
    CityList * c = *l;

    *l = (*l)->next;
    free(c);
  }
}


void printcity(cities *cityHead, CityList ** l){
 if(cityHead && !isPresent(cityHead, *l)) {
    add(cityHead, l);
    if(cityHead->w != NULL){
        printf("--");
        printf("%s West: %s\n", cityHead->name, cityHead->w->name);
        printcity(cityHead->w, l);
    }else{
        printf("--");
        printf("%s West: None\n", cityHead->name);
    }

    if(cityHead->e != NULL){
        printf("--");
        printf("%s East: %s\n", cityHead->name,cityHead->e->name);
        printcity(cityHead->e, l);

    }else{
        printf("--");
        printf("%s East: None\n", cityHead->name);
    }

    if(cityHead->s != NULL){
        printf("--");
        printf("%s South: %s\n", cityHead->name,cityHead->s->name);
        printcity(cityHead->s, l);

    }else{
        printf("--");
        printf("%s South: None\n", cityHead->name);
    }

    if(cityHead->n != NULL){
        printf("--");
        printf("%s North: %s\n", cityHead->name,cityHead->n->name);
        printcity(cityHead->n, l);

    }else{
        printf("--");
        printf("%s North: None\n", cityHead->name);
    }
 }
}

cities * newcity(char name[])
{
   cities *temp = (cities*)malloc(sizeof(cities));

   strcpy(temp->name,name);
   temp->e = temp->n = temp->s = temp->w = NULL;
   return temp;
 } 


int main()
{
  cities * c1 = newcity("c1");
  cities * c2 = newcity("c2");
  cities * c3 = newcity("c3");
  cities * c4 = newcity("c4");
  CityList * l = NULL;

  c1->e = c2;
  c2->w = c1;

  c1->s = c3;
  c3->n = c1;

  c2->s = c4;
  c4->n = c2;

  c4->w = c3;
  c3->e = c4;

  puts("[]");
  printcity(c1, &l);
  clear(&l);

  /* to make a 8 */

  cities * c5 = newcity("c5");
  cities * c6 = newcity("c6");

  c3->s = c5;
  c5->n = c3;

  c4->s = c6;
  c6->n = c4;

  c5->e = c6;
  c6->w = c5;

  puts("8");
  printcity(c1, &l);
  clear(&l);

  free(c1);
  free(c2);
  free(c3);
  free(c4);
  free(c5);
  free(c6);

  return 0;
}
```

Execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
[]
--c1 West: None
--c1 East: c2
--c2 West: c1
--c2 East: None
--c2 South: c4
--c4 West: c3
--c3 West: None
--c3 East: c4
--c3 South: None
--c3 North: c1
--c4 East: None
--c4 South: None
--c4 North: c2
--c2 North: None
--c1 South: c3
--c1 North: None
8
--c1 West: None
--c1 East: c2
--c2 West: c1
--c2 East: None
--c2 South: c4
--c4 West: c3
--c3 West: None
--c3 East: c4
--c3 South: c5
--c5 West: None
--c5 East: c6
--c6 West: c5
--c6 East: None
--c6 South: None
--c6 North: c4
--c5 South: None
--c5 North: c3
--c3 North: c1
--c4 East: None
--c4 South: c6
--c4 North: c2
--c2 North: None
--c1 South: c3
--c1 North: None
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

---

Note your definition of *newcity* is dangerous because of the line

> ```
> strcpy(temp->name,name);
> ```

where you can write out of the field *name* in *cities* in case the name is too long, producing an undefined behavior